# Java swing controls and JxBrowser page in the same frame?

Tags: java, swing, jxbrowser

I can't seem to find any information on this, is it possible to use JxBrowser to display a webpage and java swing controls within the same frame and if so, how? My current code is just one to display a window with google maps currently as I keep trying things and deleting them.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google Maps");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(1500,1000);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        browser.loadURL("http://maps.google.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BrowserView that you embed into a frame is a Swing component. You can add other Swing components in the same way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google Maps");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Let's add a button
    frame.add(new JButton("My Button"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setSize(1500,1000);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    browser.loadURL("http://maps.google.com");
}
```